# saving path on Debian

Tags: debian, environment-variables

I add this to the end of `~/.profile`

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
export PATH
```

but it is never saved. Close the terminal, open it again and the path is without the one to latex. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `.profile` gets only loaded in login  shells.
Also by default, you don't get a login shell for a GUI shell.

Either put it in e.g., `.bashrc` if you're in bash, or log out of your GUI sessions and then log back in.

You can also source it manually (`. "$HOME/.profile"`) or force a login shell with `--login`.

I find it helpful to have echo statements in these rc files so that I can know exactly when each gets loaded.

---

**Note:**
You don't need the `export` part. `PATH` already is an environment variable.

Comment: +1 for the `echo` statements in the rc files. Especially when you start spreading statements in multiple ones.

Comment: Never change `PATH` in `.bashrc`: that only applies to programs started in terminals, not to programs started from the GUI, to endless confusion. Don't put `echo` statements in `.profile`, this can confuse programs that log in remotely and run `.profile` to get desired environment variables.